# Generating pbf file directly

Tags: python, openstreetmap, osm.pbf

Currently, I'm using python code to parse and edit a .osm file and generate a new .osm file, then I convert it to a .pbf file using osmium.

The problem is that .osm files are enormous in size and I have a limited-size of HDD, I want to write the .pbf file directly.

As I searched there are some libraries for parsing .pbf files but I couldn't find anything about creating a .pbf file. Is there any library or code that can help me?